# how to get the values of two arrays to the same html javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

i have two functions in google apps script

code.gs:

```
function getdata1(e) {
// works..
return array_1;
}

function getdata2(e) {
// works..
return array_2;
}
```

index.html:

```
function getData1(e) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dispData1).getData1(e);    
}
function dispData1(array_1) {
// here i can acces the value of array_1.
// NOW i need to access the values of array_2 from the other function (getData2)
}
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

To run both functions simultaneously, use [`promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const gsr = func =>
  new Promise(res => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res)[func]());

Promise.all(['getdata1', 'getdata2'].map(f => gsr(f))).then(
  ([arr1, arr2]) => {
    console.log({ arr1, arr2 });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an intermediate function called getAllData()

```
//.gs file
function getAllData(){
  var arr1 = getdata1();
  var arr2 = getdata2();
  return {
    array_1: arr1,
    array_2: arr2
  }
}
```

And then call getAllData from your html

```
//.html file
function getAllData(e) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dispData).getAllData(e);    
}

function dispData(response) {
 var array_1 = response.array_1
 var array_2 = response.array_2
}
```